# Apache2 - Bitnami - Wordpress - httpd-adpp.conf - URL/URI Rewrite

Tags: wordpress, apache, url-rewriting, bitnami

Trying to make a rewrite rule to force HTTPS without www

**# strip WWW**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

**# force HTTPS**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have tried a million different variations.

I can strip HTTP request of the www, but it does not redirect to HTTPS

I can not strip HTTPS request of the www

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

If you always want to access your site using https://www., this configuration should be similar to the one you need to use

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/components/apache/#how-to-access-my-application-from-only-one-domain1

In your case, edit the apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf file and use the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
...

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
...
```